# Solving system of nonlinear equations using Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve a system of nonlinear equations using Matlab. I have been trying to us the fsolve() and lsqnonlin() to solve the function yet both return incorrect answers.
Specifically, I am trying to solve the Steinmetz Equation. I have the Power, the magnetic field, and the frequency and need ke, kh, and n.
The equation is P = ke*f^2*B^2 + kh*f*B^n
However, Matlab keeps giving me a value of ke less than 0 and n is less than 0.
n should be from 1-4 and ke should be a positive number less than one.

```
equations = @(x) [
    x(1)*24.57^2*1.6^2 + x(2)*24.57*1.6^x(3) - 0.4;
    x(1)*50.63^2*1.3^2 + x(2)*50.63*1.3^x(3) - 1;
    x(1)*100.4^2*1.1^2 + x(2)*100.4*1.1^x(3) - 1.9
];

x0 = [0 0 0];


solution = fsolve(equations,x0)
ke = solution(1);
kh = solution(2);
n = solution(3);




f1 = ke*24.57^2*1.6^2 + kh*24.57*1.6^n - 0.4;
f2 = ke*50.63^2*1.3^2 + kh*50.63*1.3^n - 1;
f3= ke*100.4^2*1.1^2 + kh*100.4*1.1^n - 1.9;
```

I tried fsolve and that I would get positive numbers. I understand that fsolve just looks for a solution and that there may be multiple solutions, but I can't figure how to fix this.
I have tried the lsqnonlin and adding bounds to my problem, but I think matlab runs into an issue, because it makes n equal to the lower bound no matter what.

Comment: Most likely, the system with the particular values entered do not have the solution that you expect. I tried `lsqnonlin` with lower bound `[0 0 0]` and cannot get a solution before reaching stop condition. I do not see the behavior you described. Separately, if you want to find other solutions than the one you found with the current initial try, you can always try different initial points.